# Using <select> and <input type='text'> together

Tags: php, forms, input, html-select

I'm trying to use both a `<select>` field and `<input type='text'>` field together with a $_GET method. Basically I'm hoping to have something like this:

```
<select>
    <option name='artist'>Artist</option>
    <option name='song'>Song</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='value' />
```

And then hopefully for it to redirect as `?artist=value` or `?song=value` depending on the  selected. I hope this makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<select name="artist_or_song">` will give you `?artist_or_song=artist&value=...`

Comment: are you using ajax for this?

Comment: Currently I'm not using Ajax because I've never actually looked at it. @First answer - that's not what I'm looking for, I need the url to be either ?artist=value or ?song=value because of my search queries.

Comment: Answer updated, I think I have your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Not directly.

You should attach the `name` attribute to the `select` element. Then `$_GET` will contain `your_select_name=option_value`.

Then just correlate your `$_GET['type']` and `$_GET['value']` in the backend.

```
<form method="GET">
<select name="type">
    <option value='artist'>Artist</option>
    <option value='song'>Song</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='value' />
</form>

<?php 
    echo $_GET['type']; // 'artist' or 'song'
    echo $_GET['value']; // value of text input
```

P.S.: If you need to be strict about forming your URL, you can either provide two inputs and rig up a simple JS script that will hide the input not related to your select choice.

Actually, this idea calls for a little elaboration:

```
<form method="GET">
    <select id='type'>
        <option name='artist'>Artist</option>
        <option selected name='song'>Song</option>
    </select>
    <input class='inp' id='song' type='text' name='song' />
    <input class='inp' style='display:none' id='artist' type='text' name='artist' />
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#type').change(function() {
         $('.inp').val('').hide().prop('disabled', true); // hide and clear both inputs
         $('#'+$('#type').val() ).prop('disabled', false).show(); //show input corresponding to your select
         // Note the prop('disabled') calls - you want to disable the unused input so it does not add an empty key to your query string.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response but I went with your first suggestion and it works fine, the URL I can cope with as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JordanLovelle, don't mention it, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the name attribute on the `<select>` tag.

```
<select name="Category">
    <option>Song</option>
    <option>Artist</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Value"/>
```

then it should be fairly easy to validate what have been chosen
exemple (PHP):

```
if($_GET['Category'] == "Song")
{
    //Do stuff here with $_GET['Value']
}
else if($_GET['Category'] == "Artist")
{
    //Do stuuf here with $_GET['Value']
}
```